# Can I insert Python code into the scale of an object, to get a random width?

Tags: python, particles, scale

I have created this:

[image]

And I want to randomize the width of the squares, so that there are different rectangles and not only squares... Is it possible to achieve this?

I'm not good at Python but I know something about coding and I think, that you can get a random Integer, using Python.
And is it than possible to use that code to randomize the width (Scale) of the rectangles?

Comment: Do you want to set their scale to a random value once and then just save the file as it is? Or do you want to have that random value animated / random for every frame? Or randomised every time you open the file?

Comment: It should just be a still image!

Answer (score 1):

## Method: Animation Nodes

You can use Animation Nodes addon, add all the objects to a group, and use this simple node tree:

[image: Node Tree]

## Method: Randomize Transforms

You can select the objects then use the operator: Object >> Transform >> Randomize Transform, or simply search for Randomize Transform:

[image: Randomize Transforms]

## Method: Python Script

Select the objects and run this simple script:

[image: Script]

```
import bpy
import random

objects = bpy.context.selected_objects

for obj in objects:
    obj.scale.x = random.random() * 2
```

---

You mentioned that you are not experienced in python, Animation Node is like a visual scripting system that can be used to do anything, so I recommend you use it.

Comment: I don't want to create an animation...I want it to be a still image!

Comment: @Andy No one is forcing you to. Animation nodes is an addon, and if you use some technique that works for animation you can still render a static image.

Comment: In the Python script you can replace `random.random() * 2` with `random.uniform(0, 2)`. This makes it more explicit that you want a uniform distribution in that range. Alternatively, you could use `random.gauss(1, 0.3)` to have a Gaussian distribution, which may look a bit more natural.